# How to force hyphenation in floating figure caption?

Tags: captions, hyphenation

I have a right floating figure with a justified caption spanning four lines like so:

[image: what it looks like] [image: what it should look like]

Unfortunately, LaTeX will not hyphen the words in the caption (both words hyphen just fine in regular text), although just from eye measure there seems to be more than enough space. I have tried adding the words to the `\hypenate` command, adding soft hyphens `"-` and separating a word manually, i.e. "Un- terschiedliche". None worked.

I tried increasing the width of the `wrapfigure`, still nothing (left image below). In another `wrapfigure` (right image below) it seems to work just fine, and the only difference is caption text and width of both the image and the figure itself.

[image: more wrapfigure width - nothing] [image: different image - WORKS!]

Is there a way to *force* LaTeX to hyphen at a particular syllable? Are there penalties for adding Text after a caption name/number?

Code of the first float:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/4_eadogm_footprints}
    \caption[Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs]{Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs.}
    \label{fig:4_eadogm_footprints}
    \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I realize without an MWE it is next to impossible to determine my error. I'm using [this](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/vorlagen/allgemein/) template and have unfortunately no idea how to compose an MWE with all settings intact.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Uploaded image to show what it *should* look like, rendering with `{0.33\textwidth}` and working image.

Comment: You can insert manual hyphenation patters on a case-by-case basis using `this\-is\-my\-very\-long\-word\-with\-out\-breaks`.

Comment: The code you provided isn't an "MWE", in particular, it doesn't *work* out of the box, which lowers the chance that you get an answer. And to your question, normally `babel` helps.

Comment: As I mentioned, both words hyphenate fine elsewhere in the text, so the question is not about adding hyphenation patterns, or telling LaTeX, where a word _may_ be separated. Rather, I'd like to _force_ a hyphen at an exact position. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1931751: Then why don't you just use `EA-\\DOGM-LCDs`? I guess I don't understand what "forcing a hyphen" means.

Comment: ah, valid point. I have uploaded an image to show what it should look like. Ignore the different font size. But as you can see, I'd like to force LaTeX to set the hyphen within "Abmessungen".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `babel` use

```
\caption[Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs]{%
         Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA"=DOGM"=LCDs.}
```

or at least:

```
\caption[Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs]{%
         Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM"=LCDs.}
```

That should always be done for german texts when you have a word with a hyphen. And also for small text columns use package `ragged2e` and `\RaggedRight` for the captions. Can be set automatically with `\captionsetup` and package `caption`.

As lon gas you didn't provide a *complete* example it is really difficult to say what's the problem. This works:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\setcounter{figure}{11}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/4_eadogm_footprints}
    \caption[Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs]{Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA"=DOGM"=LCDs.}
    \label{fig:4_eadogm_footprints}
    \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the `RaggedRight` would of course help to compress the text into a narrow column, but I want to have justified text. Updated the post with a second image.

Comment: the second image is easy to realize. See my edit.

Comment: well, I'd like to think so. See my 2nd edit, since it works flawlessly with a previous wrapfigure, it must be something quirky.

Comment: sorry, but creating a minimal example with your configuration _is_ easy!

Comment: bear with me, it's my first Tex document.

Comment: that makes no difference. Delete everything from the end to the problematic part. Then the same from the beginning of the document. After that delete everything in the preamble from the bottom to the top which seems not to be important and you'll find the problem!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11170/discussion-between-user1931751-and-herbert)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I believe to have found the cause and a working solution. According to [this](http://sigstp.blogspot.de/2010/09/latex-hyphenate-single-long-words-in.html) the first word of a paragraph never gets hyphenated. Seems to be the same problem with narrow columns in tables.

In order to trick LaTeX, one simply inserts a zero-width `\hspace{}` before the first word. The caption renders just fine with the following command (note that there is no space between the closing bracket of `hspace` and the first word:

```
\caption[...]{\hspace{0pt}Unterschiedliche Abmessungen der EA-DOGM-LCDs.}
```

Of course, one could define a macro to replace the original command, maybe like so:

```
\newcommand{\Caption}[2][]{\caption[#1]{\hspace{0pt}#2}}
\Caption{This is the caption text.}
\Caption[This goes into lof]{This still is the caption.}
```